# Distinct variants and $p$-cycles.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Here is a rather interesting question I found in my book

> Let $k$ and $n$ be arbitrary positive integers and let $p$ be a prime number such that $(k,p) = 1$ and $\frac{n}{2} < p \leq n.$ Let $f$ be a function of $n$ variables that have $k$ distinct variants. Show that there is a p-cycle $\sigma$ in $S_n$ such that $\sigma f = f.$

This is probably one of the hardest questions I have come across throughout my entire semester in my math class. There is just so much going on here in this problem. I know that variants are basically the different possible ways of permuting the variables in a specific function. How would one approach a problem like this because I have stared at this problem for about $20$ minutes and do not have the slightest clue at how to approach this.

I would also like some clarification at what *$(k,p) = 1$* means because I thought it was talking about the $gcd$, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $ f $ has $ k $ distinct variants is equivalent to saying that the index of the stabilizer subgroup $ H $ of $ f $ in $ S_n $ has index $ k $, i.e $ [S_n : H] = k $. Then, since $ (k, p) = 1 $ (which means that $ k, p $ are coprime, as you surmised), and since $ p \leq n $, it follows that $ p $ divides

$$ |S_n| = |H| [S_n : H] = |H|k = n! $$

We know that $ p $ doesn't divide $ k $, so it must divide $ |H| $. Now, Cauchy's theorem gives you the existence of an element of order $ p $ in $ H $. Under the given restrictions, what can the cycle structure of such an element be?

Comment: Hi Starfall. Would this just give us the desired p-cycle we need?

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, it would; but make sure you understand *why* that is the case.

Comment: Yes I understand this proof. I just needed minor clarifications, like the notation for $(k,p) = 1$. But other than that, it seems good on my end. Just to reiterate, Cauchy's theorem, in short, says that if the order of some finite group, call it $G$, is a divisor of a prime number $p$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the statement of Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Okay. I now fully understand your result. I will accept the answer and vote up.